# Не работает AJAX запрос 3

Tags: php, ajax

```js
$('#serverAdd').submit(function (e) {
  
  e.preventDefault();

  var data = $('#serverAdd').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'admin/serveradd.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(){
      alert( "Прибыли данные: " + data );
    },
    error: function(){
      alert( "Ничего небыло отправлено" );
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="serverAdd">
  <input name="serverAddName" type="text">
  <input class="inputs mb-2" name="serverAddDesc" type="text">
  <input name="serverAddAdress" type="text">
  <input name="serverAddVersion" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="serverAddSubmit" value="Создать">`
</form>
```

Comment: А что в консоле пишет, и в нетворке посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

```
    success: function(response){
        alert( "Прибыли данные: " + response );
    },
```